Errors installing Canon Printer LBP2900 on Lubuntu 24.04
I have installed Canon LBP2900 printer on Lubuntu 24.04 using the procedure given on this page for this printer. I end up with errors shown below. After installing the printer gets installed but does not print. Please guide me how to install it without errors so that I am able to print.
1) LBP-810     6) LBP3010   11) LBP3150   16) LBP3310   21) LBP5300   26) LBP6200   31) LBP7018C
2) LBP1120     7) LBP3018   12) LBP3200   17) LBP3500   22) LBP6000   27) LBP6300   32) LBP7200C
3) LBP1210     8) LBP3050   13) LBP3210   18) LBP5000   23) LBP6018   28) LBP6300n  33) LBP7210C
4) LBP2900     9) LBP3100   14) LBP3250   19) LBP5050   24) LBP6020   29) LBP6310   34) LBP9100C
5) LBP3000    10) LBP3108   15) LBP3300   20) LBP5100   25) LBP6020B  30) LBP7010C  35) LBP9200C
Please choose your printer: 4
Selected printer: LBP2900

1) Via USB
2) Through network (LAN, NET)
How is the printer connected to the computer: 1
************Driver Installation************
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease     
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libglade2-0 is already the newest version (1:2.6.4-2.4build2).
libcanberra-gtk-module is already the newest version (0.30-10ubuntu10).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
Installing common module for CUPS driver
Selecting previously unselected package cndrvcups-common.
(Reading database ... 345399 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cndrvcups-common_3.21-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cndrvcups-common (3.21-1) ...
Setting up cndrvcups-common (3.21-1) ...
Installing CAPT Printer Driver Module
Selecting previously unselected package cndrvcups-capt.
(Reading database ... 345525 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cndrvcups-capt_2.71-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cndrvcups-capt (2.71-1) ...
Setting up cndrvcups-capt (2.71-1) ...
chown: warning: '.' should be ':': ‘lp.lp’
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
apparmor-utils is already the newest version (4.0.1really4.0.0-beta3-0ubuntu0.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
Setting /usr/sbin/cupsd to complain mode.
Restarting CUPS
Installing 32-bit libraries required to run 64-bit printer driver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libatk1.0-0t64:i386' instead of 'libatk1.0-0:i386'
Note, selecting 'libgtk2.0-0t64:i386' instead of 'libgtk2.0-0:i386'
E: Unable to locate package libpango1.0-0:i386
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libpango1.0-0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpango1.0-0'
Error installing package 
Press any key to exit

Thanks
Avinash

You refer to following instructions on a page, but don't actually provide any link or detail of what page you were attempting to follow.  *The instructions you followed appear to be for releases 22.04 & older; I see libpango1.0-0:i386 only available for 22.04 & earlier - thus the failed install.  libpango1.0-0 | 1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1 | jammy-updates/universe   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x

"Unable to locate package libpango1.0-0:i386"  i386 have all been deprecated fir a long time; find an amd installer (or a better supported printer ;))

This question is similar to: Setup Canon 2900B printer in Ubunti 24.04 step by step guide for noobies like me. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Install libpango-1.0-0:i386 instead. The package has been renamed. Source: GitHub

the best method i found was in the comment/info of this youtube video with the given g drive link for the script and it works perfectly fine .....---- youtube.com/watch?v=4W9Hv1ZsEVU

add 32bit
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386


download script and place in desktop, edit the directory location inside script

open terminal in desktop give permissions to script
chmod u+r+x canon_lbp_setup.sh


run script in terminal and follow it
./canon_lbp_setup.sh 


right click on the new printer icon and click on allow launching.


